# POST request with Alamofire using parameters from Codable struct are being sent as string values instead of integers

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 5.4.

Here is the Codable parameter struct:

```
struct Parameters : Codable {
    let id: Int64
    let message: String
}
```

And here is the POST request to the server:

```
        let params = Parameters(id: 1, message: "test")
        let (targetUrl, headers) = API._generateUrlAndHeader(url)
        AF.request(targetUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let data = response.data {
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    success(json)
                    return
                }
                if let err = response.error {
                    error(err)
                    return
                }
                fatalError("should not get here")
            }
```

On calling `AF.post`, the server then receives the "id" value above as a string, not an integer.

Comment: You aren't sending JSON (as I guess you were expecting to send), as such, it's using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which encode then the data inside `httpBody` of the `URLRequest` like that: `id=1&message=test`, there is no "String/Int" distinction. Is that how you are supposed to send it?

Comment: You might want: `AF.request(targetUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers)` instead?

Comment: @Larme I see, this makes more sense now. I guess I assumed parameters would default to JSON. And adding the encoder worked!